# Docker Desktop remains stopped on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 through VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, docker

For two different laptops using Windows 7 and 10 - with `VirtualBox` **6.1.36** - the guest is `Ubuntu Desktop` **20.04** as follows

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

To install `Docker` I watched and followed the instructions according with:

- [Docker Desktop installation on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vplj9b0L_1Y)

The video covers the installation for `Docker Engine` and `Docker Desktop` respectively

The `sudo docker run hello-world` commands works as expected, so the `Docker Engine` is installed and works fine as expected, just in case more info:

```
docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.7.0

docker --version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: v1.0.28
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:02:57 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:03 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

The installation of the `Docker Desktop` is fine, but when is started through either *Applications* or *Command*, the GUI is loaded but it remains with the following message:

- *Docker Desktop **stopped...***

It remains in that state for many minutes

how resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is enable `KVM Virtualization` for `VirtualBox`, it through the `Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V` checkbox.

Having `VirtualBox` closed, execute:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VirtualMachineName> --nested-hw-virt on
```

For more details about why is used the command, read the following resources:

- [VirtualBox 6.1x: How enable 'Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V' to enable 'KVM virtualization'?](https://superuser.com/questions/1734351/virtualbox-6-1x-how-enable-enable-nested-vt-x-amd-v-to-enable-kvm-virtualiza)
- [Virtualbox enable nested vtx/amd-v greyed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251855/virtualbox-enable-nested-vtx-amd-v-greyed-out)

Answer (score 0):

Enable **Virtualization** for your system. This is not docker desktop issue.